# как считать файл изображения и затем преобразовать его в матрицу RGB в WXMaxima?

Tags: изображения

не нашел в документации ничего по этому поводу.

нужно чтобы я мог считать хотя бы xpm-файл и получить на выходе матрицу где элементом будет вектор RGB.